# Arithmetic overflow for smallint where no smallint is present

Tags: t-sql

```
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(256)
 DECLARE @IndexName VARCHAR(256)
 DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @is_unique VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @IndexTypeDesc VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @FileGroupName VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @is_disabled VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @IndexOptions VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @IndexColumnId INT
 DECLARE @IsDescendingKey INT 
 DECLARE @IsIncludedColumn INT
 DECLARE @TSQLScripCreationIndex VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @TSQLScripDisableIndex VARCHAR(MAX)

 DECLARE CursorIndex CURSOR
 FOR
    SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) [schema_name] ,
            t.name ,
            ix.name ,
            CASE WHEN ix.is_unique = 1 THEN 'UNIQUE '
                 ELSE ''
            END ,
            ix.type_desc ,
            CASE WHEN ix.is_padded = 1 THEN 'PAD_INDEX = ON, '
                 ELSE 'PAD_INDEX = OFF, '
            END
            + CASE WHEN ix.allow_page_locks = 1 THEN 'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, '
                   ELSE 'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, '
              END
            + CASE WHEN ix.allow_row_locks = 1 THEN 'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, '
                   ELSE 'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, '
              END
            + CASE WHEN INDEXPROPERTY(t.object_id, ix.name, 'IsStatistics') = 1
                   THEN 'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, '
                   ELSE 'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, '
              END
            + CASE WHEN ix.ignore_dup_key = 1 THEN 'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, '
                   ELSE 'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, '
              END + 'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,DROP_EXISTING = ON' AS IndexOptions ,
            ix.is_disabled ,
            FILEGROUP_NAME(ix.data_space_id) FileGroupName
    FROM    sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes ix ON t.object_id = ix.object_id
    WHERE   ix.type > 0
            AND ix.is_primary_key = 0
            AND ix.is_unique_constraint = 0 --and schema_name(tb.schema_id)= @SchemaName and tb.name=@TableName
            AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
            AND t.name <> 'sysdiagrams'
            AND t.name = 'LegalEntity'
    ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) ,
            t.name ,
            ix.name

 OPEN CursorIndex
 FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @IndexName,
    @is_unique, @IndexTypeDesc, @IndexOptions, @is_disabled, @FileGroupName

 WHILE ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @IndexColumns VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @IncludedColumns VARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @IndexColumns = ''
        SET @IncludedColumns = ''

        DECLARE CursorIndexColumn CURSOR
        FOR
            SELECT  col.name ,
                    ixc.is_descending_key ,
                    ixc.is_included_column
            FROM    sys.tables tb
                    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ix ON tb.object_id = ix.object_id
                    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ixc ON ix.object_id = ixc.object_id
                                                        AND ix.index_id = ixc.index_id
                    INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ixc.object_id = col.object_id
                                                  AND ixc.column_id = col.column_id
            WHERE   ix.type > 0
                    AND ( ix.is_primary_key = 0
                          OR ix.is_unique_constraint = 0
                        )
                    AND SCHEMA_NAME(tb.schema_id) = @SchemaName
                    AND tb.name = @TableName
                    AND ix.name = @IndexName
            ORDER BY ixc.index_column_id

        OPEN CursorIndexColumn 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn INTO @ColumnName, @IsDescendingKey,
            @IsIncludedColumn

        WHILE ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
            BEGIN
                IF @IsIncludedColumn = 0
                    SET @IndexColumns = @IndexColumns + @ColumnName
                        + CASE WHEN @IsDescendingKey = 1 THEN ' DESC, '
                               ELSE ' ASC, '
                          END
                ELSE
                    SET @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + @ColumnName
                        + ', ' 

                FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn INTO @ColumnName,
                    @IsDescendingKey, @IsIncludedColumn
            END

        CLOSE CursorIndexColumn
        DEALLOCATE CursorIndexColumn

        SET @IndexColumns = SUBSTRING(@IndexColumns, 1, LEN(@IndexColumns) - 1)
        SET @IncludedColumns = CASE WHEN LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
                                    THEN SUBSTRING(@IncludedColumns, 1,
                                                   LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1)
                                    ELSE ''
                               END
 --  print @IndexColumns
 --  print @IncludedColumns

        SET @TSQLScripCreationIndex = ''
        SET @TSQLScripDisableIndex = ''
        SET @TSQLScripCreationIndex = 'CREATE ' + @is_unique + @IndexTypeDesc
            + ' INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(@IndexName) + ' ON '
            + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '('
            + @IndexColumns + ') '
            + CASE WHEN LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
                   THEN CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + @IncludedColumns + ')'
                   ELSE ''
              END + CHAR(13) + 'WITH (' + @IndexOptions + ') ON '
            + '[SC_LE]([Id])' + ';'  

        IF @is_disabled = 1
            SET @TSQLScripDisableIndex = CHAR(13) + 'ALTER INDEX '
                + QUOTENAME(@IndexName) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName)
                + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' DISABLE;' + CHAR(13) 

 --print @TSQLScripCreationIndex
 --print @TSQLScripDisableIndex

        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @IndexName,
            @is_unique, @IndexTypeDesc, @IndexOptions, @is_disabled,
            @FileGroupName

    END
 CLOSE CursorIndex
 DEALLOCATE CursorIndex
```

Comment: You'll have to expand on this. Just posting a block of code is pretty much useless. What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Msg 220, Level 16, State 1, Line 905
Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 65602.

Comment: In that code there no variable specified as smallint

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: yes sql server 2016

Comment: This works for me just fine. It looks like you're trying to create your indexes in code, take a look here for an answer i provided previously; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592283/how-to-obtain-index-creation-script-when-you-know-its-name/40592332#40592332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is probably where you call `FILEGROUP_NAME()` in the `SELECT` clause of the definition of `CursorIndex`. As per the [MSDN definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176088.aspx), the `filegroup_id` parameter passed to `FILEGROUP_NAME()` is of type `smallint`. I expect you have one or more records in `sys.indexes` which have a `data_space_id` value greater than 32,767 (the maximum value which can be stored in a `smallint` variable).

You can check by running:

```
SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) [schema_name] ,
        t.name AS TableName,
        ix.name AS IndexName,
        ix.data_space_id
FROM    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ix ON t.object_id = ix.object_id
WHERE   ix.type > 0
    AND ix.is_primary_key = 0
    AND ix.is_unique_constraint = 0
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND ix.data_space_id > 32767
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
         t.name,
         ix.name
```

This will return any indexes with this problem. I can see two ways to fix your query:

1. Omit the `FILEGROUP_NAME()` call from the original cursor definition and subsequent `FETCH` calls - it doesn't look like you use it for anything later on, so there's no need for it to be included.
2. Amend the `WHERE` clause of the original cursor definition to exclude any indexes with `data_space_id` values greater than 32767. Note that this approach will mean some indexes are not included in your cursor, but these will only be the ones which have been causing it to fail anyway.

As for why SQL Server allows values greater than 32767 in `sys.indexes.data_space_id` while `FILEGROUP_NAME()` requires a `smallint` parameter, I have no idea - maybe someone else can enlighten us on this?